# No make proxy option

Tags: linked-data, groups

I have my model and i have group and i want to make it **MAKE PROXY** but there is no option. I have group it and find in the search did not get then i ungroup and find did not get. Where it is hidden or how can i make my model Make proxy option available. I have made the group and then added as group instance. Then i get the option of make proxy but and error. **Can only make proxy for a referenced object or group**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make Proxy operation only works for Groups that are linked from an external file.

To solve your problem,

1. save the file with the group in it.
2. Then create a link to the group from the external file.
3. Then on the group instance selection in the viewport create the proxy.